# Objective to Train HMM Maximize Likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, model, hidden-markov-model

An Hidden Markov Model can be utilized to model a seq of face gestures(e.g., left eye-brow up, lip pull down, right eye closed) defining a facial gesture.

I want to determine an objective to train a Hidden Markov Model such that it maximizes the likelihood of a set of sequences of facial gestures. Specifically, how do I formulate an optimization problem from this such that it could be utilized to learn the parameters of the Hidden Markov Model given that hidden states are never observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective for training HMMs is typically the likelihood with latent variables integrated out. Specifically, say you have a chain of length $N$. Denote by $Z=\{z_n\}_{n=1}^N$ the latent states and $X=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N$ the observed states (e.g. facial gestures). Further, let $\pi$ be the marginal distribution of $z_1$, $A$ the latent transition matrix with $A_{j,k}=\mathbb{P}(z_n=k|z_{n-1}=j)$ and $f(x; \theta_k) = \mathbb{P}(x_n=x|z_n=k)$ the emission distribution parameterised by $\theta_k$ (different for each latent class).

Then the joint likelihood is given by
$$ \mathbb{P}(X,Z; \pi, A,\theta) = \pi(z_1) \left( \prod_{n=2}^N A_{z_{n-1},z_n} \right) \left( \prod_{n=1}^N f(x_n;\theta_{z_n}) \right).
$$
As you say, the above quantity cannot be optimised directly, since $Z$ is not observed, so one typically integrates out the latents and maximises the resulting marginal likelihood instead:
$$ \max_{\pi, A, \theta} \sum_{Z} \pi(z_1) \left( \prod_{n=2}^N A_{z_{n-1},z_n} \right) \left( \prod_{n=1}^N f(x_n;\theta_{z_n}) \right).
$$
The integration step introduces a lot of computational complications (you cannot conveniently take logs anymore) but there is no easy way around it.  Optimisation is still possible, via the expectation-maximisation (EM) algorithm for example, but involves quite some technical sophistication. You can find a nice treatment of the topic in Christopher Bishop's book (Chapter 13).